# Mapping laravel validator errors in JS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, laravel, object

My API returns validation erros with a object like:

```
{
"message": {
    "cnpj": [
        "The cnpj field is required."
    ],
    "nome": [
        "The nome field is required."
    ]
}
```

}

How i can map each object for a `console.log()` or `li` method using pure vanilla JS?

Had tried using `error.response.data.message` but no success, because `message` is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```js
Object.entries(error.response.data.message)
  .map(([, fieldErrors]) => 
    fieldErrors.map(fieldError => <li>{fieldError}</li>)
  )
```

`Object.entries` convert an object to an array containing `[key, value]` for every key in an object, meaning:

```
let obj = {a: 1, b: 2}
console.log(Object.entries(obj)) // will become [['a', 1], ['b', 2]]
```